# Categories box not showing on post edit pages

Tags: posts, categories, wp-admin

for some reason I don't get the Categories meta box on my standard 'post' edit pages in the wp admin. It shows up on my custom post types, and they show up in the 'Quick Edit' view on the Posts list page, but not on the actual Edit Page for standard posts.

Is there a setting for it somewhere?

Comment: Have you looked in the screen options tab to see if the meta box is hidden?

Comment: Yes, there is no option to show or hide categories.

Comment: Have you disabled all your plugins and changed to a default theme to test? It might be that one of those disables it.

Comment: Why would it disable it on posts only? Categories show up fine on custom posts. I'll try it any way.

Comment: Turns out it was a function created by a previous developer!

Comment: What did the function look like? I'm having the same problem and I assume that the answer is the same. I'm struggling to find the function that's doing it, though... :-(

Comment: @Zeth see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this here as an answer for anyone else who has the same issue.

Basically, you need to do a global search of plugins and themes and look for this hook:

`remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv' , 'post' , 'normal' );`

More info in the wordpress codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

Answer (score 4):

For all who have the problem just with **Wordpress Blocks/Gutenberg**, here is the solution I was looking for a long time.

When you create a new taxonomy, make sure you've set `show_in_rest` to `true`. Otherwise it will not appear in Block editor.

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/
> Whether to include the taxonomy in the REST API. Set this to true for the taxonomy to be available in the block editor.

```
register_taxonomy(
  'new-category',
  'post',
  [
    'public' => false,
    'rewrite' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
  ]
);
```

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly for me. Thanks. Upvote from my side

Comment: Thanks man, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your issues is most likely related with [ACF/pro plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). In order to see the Categories box inside the Screen Options area this is what you have to do:

1. Go to Admin > Custom Fields.
2. Hove on a Field Group and click on Edit.
3. Under **Settings** you will find a section named **Hide on screen**.
4. Read carefully and look for Categories (it's hard to see, I missed it a couple of times).
5. Uncheck the box.
6. Go back to edit your Post type.
7. Open **Screen Options** and Categories should be there now.
8. Once your Categories box in checked you will be able to see it.

**Note:**

If this still doesn't work for you, you always can set categories on a Custom Post Type using the **Quick Edit** function.

Comment: No, don't have ACF plugin installed. The answer was as I have stated above, the remove_meta_box hook had been added in by a previous developer.

Answer (score 0):

find a very stupid solution. get back to the product list in woocommerce. in every product is a link that says. fast edit (or something like that) > click on it > you would be able to see your categories in the left panel list.
that's it !
that was weird !